# Shortening Repetitive Code in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I'm starting to get the hang of this. For this code:

```
printedxrow7 = ["V "+str(cols[0].count(0)),"V "+str(cols[1].count(0)),"V "+str(cols[2].count(0)),"V "+str(cols[3].count(0)),"V "+str(cols[4].count(0))]
printedxrow8 = [str(sum(cols[0])),str(sum(cols[1])),str(sum(cols[2])),str(sum(cols[3])),str(sum(cols[4]))]
numgood = (((rows[0]).count(2))+((rows[0]).count(3)+(rows[1]).count(2))+((rows[1]).count(3))+((rows[2]).count(2))+((rows[2]).count(3))+((rows[3]).count(2))+((rows[3]).count(3))+((rows[4]).count(2))+((rows[4]).count(3)))
```

I'm thinking to condense this to:

```
rows = [[convert[random.randint(0,7)] for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
cols = list(zip(*rows))
printedrows = ["\n"+ "[X]"*5 + "  <- V: {}   TOTAL: {}".format(row.count(0), sum(row)) for row in rows]
printcolvolt = ["V:{}".format(col.count(0) for col in cols)]
printcolcount = ["T:{}".format(sum(col) for col in cols)]
numgood = numtiles - rows.count(0)
```

Why do I get the  at 0x030116C0> error? (I added the rest of the code for context.)

Comment: Is it just that you forgot the parentheses after `col.count(0)` and `sum(col)`?

Comment: that "error" is not an error, it's you printing a generator object.

Comment: As you 'get the hang' of this, follow the formatting guidelines in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Specifically, use some whitespace and limit the line length to 79 characters so your code is easier for others to read. List comprehensions can be broken logically into multiple lines to aid readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a `SyntaxError` (missing closing parenthesis on the `format` call) in lines 1 and 2, and have put it in the wrong place when editing your post.

```
printcolvolt = ["V:{}".format(col.count(0)) for col in cols]
                                          ^
```

Otherwise, you format the generator `col.count(0) for col in cols` itself, rather than the values it generates.

For line 3, I think you should have something like

```
numgood = sum(row.count(2) + row.count(3) for row in rows)
```

otherwise, you are trying to count how many zeroes there are in what I assume is a list of lists, which will always give zero. I don't know what `numtiles` is.

N.B. It would be more helpful if you said what the problem actually was (e.g. input, expected output, actual output/error) rather than just "why wouldn't this work".

Comment: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x030116C0> is the error it gives me. Also, I had edited my code before posting and forgot to recopy, sorry.

Comment: You have put the closing parenthesis in the wrong place, so that you are formatting the generator not its results! I will put an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the parentheses right after the function you are referring to:

```
printcolvolt = ["V:{}".format(col.count(0)) for col in cols]
printcolcount = ["T:{}".format(sum(col)) for col in cols]
```

Otherwise,

```
#WRONG
printcolvolt = ["V:{}".format(col.count(0) for col in cols)]
```

will create a `generator object` (which you see with `generator object <genexpr> at ...`) and try to print this, because the `for ... in` is inside the parentheses.